# Trying to Logout using broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

> What am I doing Wrong?

Activity Flow:
`HomeActivity` --> `SettingActivity` --> `ProfileActivity`

In `ProfileActivity` I have `LogOut` button. `OnClick` LogOut I doing...

```
 public void onLogout()
{
    //do this on logout button click
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.package.ACTION_LOGOUT");
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

And in `SettingsActivity` `onCreate` I am doing this...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.package.ACTION_LOGOUT");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("onReceive","Logout in progress");
            //At this point we should start the login activity and finish this one.
            Intent gotoLogin = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,Login_Activity.class);
            startActivity(gotoLogin);
            finish();
        }
    }, intentFilter);
}
```

I thought I will logout from the `ProfileActivity` but I not.
What is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use intent flags to clear out your activity stack, refer this for more details https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

So you need to implement your onLogout() method like below and you are good to go

```
public void onLogout() {
    //do this on logout button click
    Intent logoutUser = new Intent(context, Login_Activity.class);
    logoutUser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(logoutUser);
}
```

Note: Also clear your shared preference session or local databases related to user profile if you are using any of it

Comment: This Works like charm but it clears `Activity` stack of `LoginActivity` and `NewUserActivity` which is behind `LoginActivity`

Comment: Yes are we are adding flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK" so it will clear out the current task, I guess that is the intended behaviour of logout, please tell me if I missed anything

Comment: Also it is not good development practice to close activities with broadcast receiver, specifically when you want achieve something like logout, please refer to the link which I mentioned in my answer to find out appropriate intent flag for your need.

Answer (score 0):

Send broadcast like this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing Wrong?

You are mixing two kinds of `BroadcastReceivers`. One is the global broadcast and the other the local broadcast.

So, you change the code to:

onClick -> `sendBroadcast(intent);`
onCreate-> `registerReceiver(...);`

or

onClick -> `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);`
onCreate -> `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(...);`

If you need to broadcast events only within your application, then the latter option is recommented.